# Networkx: Network with parallel edges

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I need to develop a bipartite network where nodes come from the 'id_emp' and 'name_dep' columns of the dataframe below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp':[13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114],
                   'name_emp':['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin'],
                   'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo'],
                   'peso': [8,9,10,11]})
```

On the edges:

1 - They have weight, determined by the 'weight' column;

2 - They must be directed;

3 - In orgininal work must demonstrate a relation of exchange, then between two nodes, there must be two parallel edges;

I am trying with the following code:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
deputados = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]

G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
empresa = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'peso']].values)
edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

deputado = "Ronaldo"

lista_subset_graph = list(df[df["name_dep"] == deputado]["id_emp"]) + [deputado]
H = G.subgraph(lista_subset_graph)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(H, pos = nx.spring_layout(H), nodelist = deputados, node_color='#bfbf7f', node_shape="h", node_size=3000, with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(H, pos = nx.spring_layout(H), nodelist = empresa, node_color='#9f9fff', node_size=3000, with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(H, pos = nx.spring_layout(H),width=edge_width, alpha=0.2)

#nx.draw(H, style = "solid", with_labels = True)
plt.figure(figsize=(7.5, 7.5))
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

When I comment the lines started by `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` and `nx.draw_networkx_edges` and uncomment the line started by `nx.draw` the output is as follows:

[image]

I would like to keep a preview as the first image that meets the specs for the edges.

Comment: To have parallel edges and direction, you'll need `G` to be a `MultiDiGraph`, not a `Graph`.

Comment: even using MultiDiGraph, the result is the same. The nodes do not connect.